# Real time example and use of AIDL in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, process, aidl

I would like to know the real time example for aidl and use of it.I studied android developer blog regarding this topic. I could not realize it with real time world.Can anyone tell me with an example.

Comment: What are you calling real time ? From my recent tests, an AIDL call takes around 20 ms to be sent to the remote service (providing the service is already bound).

Answer (score 1):

AIDL is used for sharing data in certain format (`primitive` and `parcelable`) with other applications.

Real world example can be like creating a **School Application** ( which holds all student, teacher and admission related data/information).

1. Now there in another application in market place which processes student information and suggest some good course to limited set of student based on subject they have selected.
2. There can be another application which helps school in hiring their staff for which they might require staff/teachers information.

So School app contains large data which can be shared with other applications which can be done easily with AIDL.

Data can be exchanged in Parcelable classes format as :

```
public class Student implements Parcelable {}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can we use content provider instead of that ?

Comment: This can be achieved with content providers ryt?